# Most idiomatic way of applying modulo to list in python

Tags: python

Currently I have a list with some non-repeating positive integers in it say `a = [1,2,6,15,19]`

What is the most idiomatic way to create a function that returns a new list that is the result of taking the modulo `%x` of each element of `a` without having any repeated elements in the output?

Specifically I want `f(a,x)` to return `[1%x,2%x,6%x,15%x,19%x]` without the repeated elements.

For example `f([1,2,6,15,19],4)` would return `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Is it important to return a list? Or any iterable would do? If any iterable is okay, sets are idiomatic: `def f(a, x): return {i % x for i in a}`.

Comment: Order of the output isn't especially important. Pretty sure any iterable would do here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, and a `set()` to filter out duplicates and preserve order:

```
def f(values, x):
    seen = set()
    add = seen.add
    return [res for res in (i % x for i in values) if res not in seen and not add(res)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> f([1,2,6,15,19], 4)
[1, 2, 3]
```

If order does not need to be preserved, just use a set comprehension instead and return the resulting set:

```
def f(values, x):
    return {i % x for i in values}
```

Comment: I understand that `if not add(res)` is a way of calling `add` on `res` but why is `add(res)` always False?

Comment: @simon: because the method returns `None`; it alters the set in-place. `None` is false in a boolean context.

Answer (score 4):

To return the list of the set you need a set comprehension wrapped in a list.

```
def f(l, x):
    return list({i % x for i in l})
```

As per question comments, returning the set may be the best option.

```
def f(l, x):
    return {i % x for in l}
```

Comment: If performance isn't an issue, and the order itself isn't super-important, I might use `sorted` instead of `list` to guarantee a canonical return order without having to go through contortions.  It'll be fast enough in practice.

Comment: @DSM agreed.  I  haven't benchmarked `sorted` vs. `list` so I'm not sure where it falls behind...

Comment: @Justin: `sorted()` copies the values into a list first, *then* sorts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I just don't know how much overhead is associated with that... i.e. how long of a list can you have before the copy is significantly slower than the coercion... but as per the comments in the question, I thin returning the set as is  will be the best option.